# Is it safe to use not initialized yet instance of Context class to create objects from Android SDK ?

Tags: java, android, initialization

For instance, to initialize `Toast` as *final* field in `Activity` class using this `activity` as `Context`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final Toast TOAST_WARNING = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    // skip

    private void onWarning() {
        TOAST_WARNING.show();
    }

}
```

Or should I initialize such classes from Android SDK in `onCreate()` method of `Activity` class.

Or may be it depends on which class I use?

Comment: I would suggest to just create the toast right inside of onWarning(). There is no need to pre-create it and it won't hurt if multiple warnings happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely need to initialize the activity first. The toast can stay an instance variable (just not final), but it just needs to be initialized in `onCreate`:

```
private Toast warningToast;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the Activity's layout (optional)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize the toast
    warningToast = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

If you try to use `this` when the activity wasn't yet instantiated properly you'll get an NPE error.

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible. But you must get the Context from your own subclass of Application.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

private static Context _context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    _context = this;
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return _context;
}
}
```

//MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final Toast TOAST_WARNING = Toast.makeText(MyApp.getContext(), "warning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

private void onWarning() {
    TOAST_WARNING.show();
}

}
```

And set the `name` attribute of your AndroidManifest with the name of your subclass of Application.

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
```

Comment: could someone explain to me why my answer has been downvoted?